# Why cursor resets to default after scene switch in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I know that I can set cursor type for the entire scene using `Scene.setCursor` method. But if I swap the scene with another one, cursor always resets to default - disregarding the cursor set on new scene. Here's the test case, tested in XFCE and XMonad:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Cursor;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class HideCursor extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.setStyle("-fx-background-color: green");
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 600);
        scene.setCursor(Cursor.MOVE);

        StackPane root2 = new StackPane();
        root2.setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue");
        Scene scene2 = new Scene(root2, 600, 600);
        scene2.setCursor(Cursor.MOVE);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

        Button switchScene = new Button("switch");
        root.getChildren().add(switchScene);
        switchScene.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                primaryStage.setScene(scene2);
            }
        });

        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Interestingly, in Windows 7 it works as expected. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Same issue with LinuxMint 17.2 cinamon!